# How to create multiple forms in one page with multiple submit buttons in APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, survey

I am creating a survey application in oracle apex that has multiple tabs for survey in one page. However, it is not allowing me to submit one tab at a time and is throwing errors like-

1 error has occurred
Column QUES9 not found in table CUST_FB_RU2C

I think its trying to submit all forms at once. What should be done?

Comment: How did you put the tabs together? How did you create multiple forms on one page? What version of APEX are you using? I just ran a test in 19.1 where I created multiple forms on a single page using the create page wizard multiple times (the first time created the page and the second time just added new components to the existing page). Then changed the button names in each region so I could tell them apart. Finally, I used conditions to lock down processes to the correct button. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to submit only once, at the end of the survey.

Another option (if you want to allow partial submits) is to create one page per group of questions in the survey and submit page-by-page.

Or - if it has to be one page - then you'll have to create your own *submitting logic* and write your own processes which will perform database insert action, inserting only items which are relevant to each of those submit buttons.